# How do you use document.write() to make a dynamic web page, so when you click a button it goes shows a results page like in this video

Tags: javascript, html

https://youtu.be/5IA8tzjPqqw

This is what I have so far:
I am trying to get the Process button to take the inputs from the text boxes and return a page with results similar to that in the video. Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Payroll Processing Program</title> <!--Jason Kim Section 17 -->
    <style>
        body{background-color:lightgray}
        h1{text-align: center; color: lightblue; background-color: white}
        h2{text-align: center; color: lightblue; background-color: white}

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Payroll Processing</h1>
    <h2>Report Generator</h2>
    <hr>
    <script>
    var Department, Salary;
    var ID1, HrWorked1, HrlySal1;
    var ID2, HrWorked2, HrlySal2;
    var ID3, HrWorked3, HrlySal3;

    function Processing(Sal){
    document.write(Department);
    if (HrWorked1 <= 40){
        Sal=HrWorked1 * HrlySal1;
        }
    else {Sal=HrWorked1 * (HrlySal1 * 1.5);
    }
        return Sal;
    document.write("Department Overtime Salaries:" Sal);
    }
    </script>

    <form name="PayrollProcessing">
    Department: <input type="text" id="deptName" value="" size="10" onchange="Department=deptName.value"/>
    <hr>
    <pre>       ID        Hours Worked  Hourly Salary</pre>
    Employee 1: <input type="text" id="EmpID1" value="" size="10" onchange="ID1=EmpID1.value"/>
    <input type="text" id="HrWorked1" value="" size="10" onchange="Hr1=HrWorked1.value"/>
    <input type="text" id="HrlySal1" value="" size="10" onchange="Sal1=HrlySal1.value"/>
    <br>
    Employee 2: <input type="text" id="EmpID2" value="" size="10" onchange="ID2=EmpID2.value"/>
    <input type="text" id="HrWorked2" value="" size="10" onchange="Hr2=HrWorked2.value"/>
    <input type="text" id="HrlySal2" value="" size="10" onchange="Sal2=HrlySal2.value"/>
    <br>
    Employee 3: <input type="text" id="EmpID3" value="" size="10" onchange="ID3=EmpID3.value"/>
    <input type="text" id="HrWorked3" value="" size="10" onchange="Hr3=HrWorked3.value"/>
    <input type="text" id="HrlySal3" value="" size="10" onchange="Sal3=HrlySal3.value"/>
    <hr>

    <button onclick="Processing(Salary)">Process</button>
    <button onclick="formClear()">Clear</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you to anyone who can help!!
Much Appreciated :)

Comment: Don't use document.write. Select an element with document.querySelectorAll or document.querySelector and then use the innerHTML property of the DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

## Issues In Your Code

1. You miss a `+` for `document.write("Department Overtime Salaries:" Sal);` You need to change it to `document.write("Department Overtime Salaries:" + Sal);`
2. I don't think you need `Salary` parameter in `Procesing()`
3. You have `document.write("Department Overtime Salaries:" + Sal);` after `return`. Code after `return` will not be genereated. You can simply delete `return Sal;`
4. Wrong variable name used in `Processing()`. You declare `Hr1 = HrWorked1.value` for `onchange` but used `HrWorked1` in `Processing()`. You should use `Hr1` instead.

**After theses fixes, you should be able to use input in your function. All you need is markup your data using HTML.**

## Example Working Code Using above Fix

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Payroll Processing Program</title> <!--Jason Kim Section 17 -->
    <style>
        body{background-color:lightgray}
        h1{text-align: center; color: lightblue; background-color: white}
        h2{text-align: center; color: lightblue; background-color: white}

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Payroll Processing</h1>
    <h2>Report Generator</h2>
    <hr>
    <script>
    var Department, Salary;
    var ID1, HrWorked1, HrlySal1;
    var ID2, HrWorked2, HrlySal2;
    var ID3, HrWorked3, HrlySal3;

    function Processing(){
    document.write("<h2>Department: "+Department+"</h2>");
    if (HrWorked1 <= 40){
        Sal=Hr1 * Sal1;
        }
    else {Sal=Hr1 * (Sal1 * 1.5);
    }
    document.write("<h3>Department Overtime Salaries: " + Sal+"</h3>");
    }
    </script>

    <form name="PayrollProcessing">
    Department: <input type="text" id="deptName" value="" size="10" onchange="Department=deptName.value"/>
    <hr>
    <pre>       ID        Hours Worked  Hourly Salary</pre>
    Employee 1: <input type="text" id="EmpID1" value="" size="10" onchange="ID1=EmpID1.value"/>
    <input type="text" id="HrWorked1" value="" size="10" onchange="Hr1=HrWorked1.value"/>
    <input type="text" id="HrlySal1" value="" size="10" onchange="Sal1=HrlySal1.value"/>
    <br>
    Employee 2: <input type="text" id="EmpID2" value="" size="10" onchange="ID2=EmpID2.value"/>
    <input type="text" id="HrWorked2" value="" size="10" onchange="Hr2=HrWorked2.value"/>
    <input type="text" id="HrlySal2" value="" size="10" onchange="Sal2=HrlySal2.value"/>
    <br>
    Employee 3: <input type="text" id="EmpID3" value="" size="10" onchange="ID3=EmpID3.value"/>
    <input type="text" id="HrWorked3" value="" size="10" onchange="Hr3=HrWorked3.value"/>
    <input type="text" id="HrlySal3" value="" size="10" onchange="Sal3=HrlySal3.value"/>
    <hr>

    <button onclick="Processing()">Process</button>
    <button onclick="formClear()">Clear</button>

</body>
</html>
```